# Web API works locally, throws JSON error when published

Tags: angularjs, json

I have created a Web API which returns data using AngularJS and when run locally the data displays in my web page.  I then publish the local Web API to my web host and point my AngularJS code to the web host, but then I get the error: "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data".  Below is my AngularJS code.  What setting on my web host might I be able to change to get this to work?

You can test the Web API at http://stevegaines.info/api/Exams?id=1&extra=0

```js
    var oApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

    oApp.controller("certificationsCtrl", function ($scope, $http)
    {
        $scope.Exams = {};
        $scope.ShowExams = function (certificationID)
        {
            var url = "http://stevegaines.info/api/Exams?id=" + certificationID + "&extra=0";
            //var url = "http://localhost:49861/api/Exams?id=" + certificationID + "&extra=0";
            $http({
                method: "GET",
                url: url,
                headers: { "Accept": "application/json" }
            }).then(function mySuccess(response)
            {
                alert("response.data = " + response.data);
                $scope.Exams = response.data;
            }, function myError(response)
            {
                alert("error response.statusText = " + response.statusText);
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: Aren't you trying to parse an XML file to a JSON file? I think that's why he's consfused

Comment: the angular code doesn't matter, you have to check in the "network" section of the developpers tools of the navigator. You will be able to see the response of the server, i'm sure the content is wrong.

Comment: It could be that the API is returning an error due to an installation problem.

Comment: @Greg: he uses it locally where it works, it wont change from xml to json magically if he installs it on a server.

Comment: Greg, but it works locally with no change to the code.  It seems to get the JSON object it wants locally, but it comes back in XML when it's on the web host.

Comment: Pierre, I did what you said before I made the post.  That's where I got the JSON.parse error message, in the Developer Tools Network section.

Comment: Do you have a config file in your API, specific to the installation ?

Comment: you got the "JSON.parse error message" in the "console" section. But in fact you will see the xml in the network section, so the pb comes from the installation of the API. The problems isn't in the angular app.

Comment: Pierre, I ran it in Firefox, displayed the Network tab of Developer Tools and I clicked on Response, that's where I saw the JSON.parse error.  Not Console.  I just double-checked.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111544/discussion-between-pierre-emmanuel-lallemant-and-steve-gaines).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was CORS - Cross origin resource sharing.  In other words, the call was from a different domain and for that to work I need to enable CORS.